# See individual USB packets in wireshark, not URBs

Tags: linux, usb, wireshark

I'm developing a high-speed USB peripheral and using Wireshark to sniff the USB traffic.  In Wireshark, each line displayed corresponds to a single URB.

Because I'm developing on the device side, I don't really care about URBs, instead, I'd like to see individual packets.

For instance, during a single control transfer, this is what I see in Wireshark:

[image]

But this one control transfer consists of 9 packets in the following sequence:

```
    {{SETUP, DATA0, ACK}, {IN, DATAx, ACK}, {OUT, ZLP, ACK}}
```

Can I see the exact timing and contents of each of these packets, or is that something that I would need to buy a hardware USB analyzer for?

My operating system is vanilla Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I am pretty sure the Linux kernel is not able to spit out packets in another granularity than URBs.

Comment: @tofro I suspect that you're right, but I'm hoping that there is some sort of work around!